# copy all rows between two values where the first value is variable

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I want to loop and extract all the rows between two different words (For Example, 56050067 and 56050068) that repeat in a column. This code get me just the first range

Thank you for intance

My table like this:

56060067
A
B
C
D
F
56060068
J
H
I
K
L
56043556
T
Y
J
K
N
56060067
O
P
Q
W
X
56060068
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Code:

```
Sub copy()

    Dim rownum As Long
    Dim colnum As Long
    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim endrow As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim s As Range
    Dim e As Range
    rownum = 1
    colnum = 1

    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'or this can be any other sheet where you search

        Set r = .Range("B:B").Find("56050067")
        If Not r Is Nothing Then

            Set e = .Range("B:B").Find("56050068", r).Offset(-1)
            If Not e Is Nothing Then
                .Range(r, e).EntireRow.copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") 'or to whatever sheet
            End If

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do `56050067` and `56050068` always appear as a pair? What would you like to do if one is missing? Consider a sequence `67, 65, 67, 69, 68, 70, 68`, what do you want to do? Or can you guarantee that this would never be in your data?

Comment: What do you mean loop? Do you want to extract this over and over? as if the same words repeat?

Comment: My table like this:

56060067 A B C D F 56060068 J H I K L 56043556 T Y J K N 56060067 O P Q W X 56060068 . . . . . . . and i  want to extract rows between the two numbers

Answer (score 0):

So I have it loop until it reaches end of range in B, keep in mind in your macro aka the one I modified, it is searching for those numbers specifically.

```
 Sub copy()

    Dim rownum As Long
    Dim colnum As Long
    Dim startrow As Long
    Dim endrow As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim xLastrow As Long
    Dim s As Range
    Dim e As Range
    rownum = 1
    colnum = 1

    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
LoopHere:
    xLastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set e = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & lastrow)

    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'or this can be any other sheet where you search

        Set s = .Range(s, e).Find("56050067")
        If Not s Is Nothing Then

            Set e = .Range(s, e).Find("56050068", s)
            If Not e Is Nothing Then
                .Range(s, e).EntireRow.copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & xLastrow) 'or to whatever sheet
            End If

        End If

    End With

    Set s = e.Offset(1).Resize(lastrow)

    If e.Row > lastrow Or e.Row = lastrow Then
    Else
    GoTo LoopHere
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: yes i want to extract all data(Rows) between the two values. The Two values were several time in table

Comment: Done this will go through column B and get the values back

Comment: let me know if this does not work, or mark it done if it does thanks

Comment: IIt's ok. but there is one problem with the last row because he didn't stop on it

Answer (score 0):

you could filter on wanted "pair" of numbers and then loop through filtered cells "pairs"

```
Sub copy()    
    Dim iArea As Long
    Dim found As Range, area As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'reference sheet1
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column B cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("56060067", "56060068"), Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filter referenced range with wanted numbers pair
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set found = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' if any filtered cell other then header then store it in 'found' range to
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filter
        If Not found Is Nothing Then ' if wanted pairs found
            With found ' reference found cells
                For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count Step 2 ' loop through found range "pairs" of cells
                    .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea).Offset(1), .Areas(iArea + 1).Offset(-1)).EntireRow.copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' copy rows in between current "pair" and paste them to sheet2 from its column A first empty cell cells
                Next
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```